# How to use link with hover on iOS phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code

```
<div id="hover">
<a href="website">               
    <img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="img1">
    <img style="display:none;" class="img2" src="img2">                 
</a>
</div>
```

and jquery, that change display on hover.

```
  $("#hover").hover(function () {
   change display
}, function () {
  change display to default setup
});
```

Problem is on phones with iOS. User must click 2 times, to activave link and it´s unfriendly. (On android is 1 click enough). How can i sole this problem, to make one click enough on iOS.

Comment: `The :hover selector is used to select elements when you mouse over them.` do you have any mouse in iOS?

Comment: Use `touchstart` for phone

Comment: The fundamental problem is there is no mouse to trigger the hover - you need to think about UI design differently for phones/tablets

Comment: `$('#hover').on({ 'touchstart' : function(){ /* do something... */ } });`

Comment: This is a really more of a UI/UX decision than a programming one.